# Ignore order of elements in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

Is it possible to ignore order of elements in `IEnumerable`, like in `Assert.That( ... , Is.EquivalentTo( ... ));`, but using [`TestCaseData.Returns()`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestCaseData.html) in NUnit 3?

Comment: Could you edit the question to make it clearer with a bit of pseudo-code that shows what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write test cases in NUnit to determine whether two lists are of identical length and contain the same elements, ignoring the order of the elements.

If my interpretation of your question is correct then I have included an example below which should solve your problem:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), nameof(MyDataClass.TestCases))]
    public bool ListEqualTest(IEnumerable<int> list1, IEnumerable<int> list2)
    {
        return list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count() && list1.Count == list2.Count;
    }
}

public class MyDataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var list2 = new List<int> { 3, 4, 2, 1, 5 };

            var list3 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            var list4 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 11, 12 };
          
            yield return new TestCaseData(list1, list2).Returns(true);
            yield return new TestCaseData(list3, list4).Returns(false);
        }
    }  
}
```

I adapted the example provided in the NUnit documentation, found [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestCaseData.html).

My solution obviously makes use of the primitive type `int` when defining the `IEnumerable<int>` parameters and constructing the `List<int>` objects but it won't take much effort at all to adapt it for your specific needs.

Hope this helps.